# Scroll Thumb into direct place of ScrollBar WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

How to choose position in `ScrollBar` and move there `Thumb`? And what i should add to shift `Thumb` on one position of mine information at `ScrollBar`?

```
    <Style x:Key="ScrollBarPageButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                    <Border BorderBrush="Transparent"></Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="ScrollBarThumbStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1,0,1,0" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                    <Border  CornerRadius="4" Width="10">
                        <Border.Background>
                            <RadialGradientBrush>
                                <GradientStop Color="#FF322E2E"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#FF363232" Offset="0.385"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#FF2B2626" Offset="1"/>
                            </RadialGradientBrush>
                        </Border.Background>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="VerticalScrollBar" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
        <Border CornerRadius="5" Width="14" >
            <Border.Background>
                <RadialGradientBrush>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF645B5B" Offset="0.923"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF685F5F" Offset="0"/>
                </RadialGradientBrush>
            </Border.Background>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Track Name="PART_Track" Grid.Row="1" 
               IsDirectionReversed="True" ViewportSize="28" >
                    <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                        <RepeatButton Command="ScrollBar.PageUpCommand" Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButtonStyle}">
                        </RepeatButton>
                    </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                    <Track.Thumb>
                        <Thumb Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarThumbStyle}">
                        </Thumb>
                    </Track.Thumb>
                    <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                        <RepeatButton Command="ScrollBar.PageDownCommand" Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButtonStyle}">
                        </RepeatButton>
                    </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                </Track>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource VerticalScrollBar}"/>
    </Style>
```